# Angularjs ngRoute is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-routing, ngroute

i have an index page(login ) in which register link is present so while redirecting i am trying to load the controller but it is not loading also there is no error in console.

My home page is getting loaded with URL : http://localhost:8081/WebServices/
and after clicking resgiter i am trying to rediect it to : http://localhost:8081/WebServices/#/regsiter

Help would be appreciated.

My index.html page

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login Page</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src= "/WebServices/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "/WebServices/js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "/WebServices/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "/WebServices/js/friendsCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "/WebServices/js/friendsService.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "/WebServices/js/loginCtrl.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
</head>

<body>
   <div ng-app="loginApp">

      <div class="col-md-3">

    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form name="loginform" role="loginform" ng-submit="login()">

        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error':loginform.username.$dirty && loginform.username.$error.required }" >
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" required />
            <span ng-show="loginform.username.$dirty && loginform.username.$error.required " class="help-block">Username is required</span> 
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error':loginform.username.$dirty && loginform.username.$error.required }">
            <label for="Password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" required />
            <span ng-show="loginform.password.$dirty && loginform.password.$error.required " class="help-block">Password is required</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type ="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="loginform.$invalid">Login</button>
            <a href="#/regsiter" class="btn btn-link">Resgiter</a>
        </div>


    </form>
</div>

</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

loginCtrl.js file

```
var loginApp=angular.module('loginApp',['ngRoute']);

loginApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/' , { 
            templateUrl:'index.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
        })
        .when('/regsiter' , { 
            templateUrl:'registration_ang.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo:'/'
        });

}]);


loginApp.controller('loginCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
    console.log("controller loaded");
    alert("controller loaded");
    $scope.login=function(){
        console.log("inside loginCtrl : login function");
        alert("checking login.");
    };
}

]
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed to add `ng-view` directive on your page, so that will load the template & controller configured on `$routeProvider` inside `ng-view` directive element.

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

Comment: should  this be added on every page.?

Comment: @user3718420 it should be added on your `index.html` page only once..so that will put the inner content based on route definition

Comment: @user3718420 Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Comment: but if we add <div ng-view></div> tag in index.html (which in my case is login page with register link) it will load the registration page content in index.html but it won't redirect to registration page . please suggest how can i achieve redirection also.

Comment: No errors on console. but my registration page is loading in login page itself.

Comment: because you kept it inside your `index.html` itself..what I'd suggest is you should create new route `.when('/login' , { 
            templateUrl:'login.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
        })` and then move that html inside `login.html` so when you have `/login` url then your login page will shown

Comment: yeah , i will create a new route for login . Thanks again Pankaj . :)

Comment: sorry my acceptance won't appear as i don't have enough reputation for now .

Comment: @user3718420 visit [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) would help you.